# Verilog SRAM controller

Tags: verilog, simulation, hdl, multisim

I am trying to implement a SRAM controller module. It's structured as follows

External connections:

- extA[18:0] -- address
- extIO[7:0] -- bidirectional input/output
- OE,WE,CE  -- control signals

Internal connections:

- intA[17:0] -- address
- intIO[15:0] -- bidirectional input/output
- EN,RDY,RW -- control singals

Basically I am trying to implement a module that splits intIO into two sequential extIOs.
Here is a code I've come up with so far:

```
module SRAM_Controller(clk,intA,intIOin,intIOout,extA,extIO,OE,WE,CE,rw,en,reset,rdy);
  input  clk, en, rw,reset,rdy;
  input [17:0] intA;
  input [15:0] intIOin;
  output reg [15:0] intIOout;
  output reg [18:0] extA;
  inout [7:0] extIO;
  output reg OE,WE,CE;

  reg [7:0] Dout;
  reg [15:0] Din;
  reg counter = 1'b0;
  assign extIO = (rdy && OE) ? Dout: 8'bz;

  always @(posedge clk)
  begin
      if (reset) begin
      //RESET?
      end
      else begin
          if (en) begin
             CE<=1'b0;
             if(rdy) begin
                extA[17:0]<=intA;
                extA[18] <= counter;
                case(rw)
                1'b0: // WRITE
                     begin
                        case(counter)
                        1'b0: begin
                                WE<=1'b0;
                                OE<=1'b1;
                                Dout<=intIOin[7:0];
                                counter<=1'b1;
                              end
                        1'b1: begin
                                Dout<=intIOin[15:8];
                                counter<=1'b0;
                              end
                        endcase

                     end
                1'b1: // READ
                     begin
                        case(counter)
                            1'b0:
                                begin 
                                    WE<=1'b1;
                                    OE<=1'b0;
                                    intIOout[7:0]=extIO;
                                    counter<=1'b1;
                                end
                            1'b1:
                                begin
                                    extA[18]<=1'b1;
                                    intIOout[15:8]<=extIO;
                                    counter<=1'b0;
                                end
                        endcase
                    end
              endcase
          end
       end
       else begin
           CE<=1'b1;
       end
   end
end
endmodule
```

And here is a testbench for it:

```
module SRAM_Controller_tb();
reg clk;
reg [17:0] intA;
wire [15:0] intIOin;
wire [15:0] intIOout;
wire [18:0] extA;
wire [7:0]  extIO;
reg  rw, en, reset,rdy;
wire OE, WE, CE;
reg [15:0] datout;
wire [15:0] datin;
SRAM_Controller DUT(.clk(clk),.intA(intA),.intIO(intIO),.extA(extA),
.extIO(extIO),.OE(OE),.WE(WE),.CE(CE),.rw(rw),.en(en),.reset(reset),.rdy(rdy));

assign datin = intIO;
assign intIOin = !rw ? datout: 16'bz;

initial begin
   #1
   clk = 0;
   en = 1;
   rdy = 1;
   rw = 0;
   intA = 18'b010010001100111001;
   datout<= 16'hCA7E;
   #4
   intA = 18'b100001001000001111;
   datout<= 16'h23F6;
   #6
   rdy = 0;
   rw = 1;
   intA = 18'b0;    
   #4
   rdy =1;
   #4
   rdy = 0; 
end
always begin
   #1 clk = !clk;
end
endmodule
```

This is simulation from ModelSim for it:[image]

I would like to know how to fix these issues:

- extIO signal lags behind extA for one clock cycle ( I am not sure which part of my code causes delay)
- extIO and intIOout signals retain "F6" bits from previous write transaction.

Please forgive me for any obvious mistakes in the code, it's my fist time using Verilog.

Comment: To start with, you're really not going to want a bidirectional bus *inside* your FPGA. Keep it as two separate unidirectional buses.

Comment: More to the point, you can't have bidirectional signals inside the FPGA, only at the I/O pins. All internal signals are unidirectional. You need to implement three signals for a bidirectional bus: bus signals in; bus signals out; tri-state bus driver enable. Look at your FPGA's documentation, see the circuit diagram for the I/O pin buffer. That circuit is what your logic design must use and control.

Comment: I've replaced bidirectional intIO with intIOin and intIOout buses. https://pastebin.com/f8ADFqGh This is what I get. http://imgur.com/a/5oEaw 
It still gets these values from the previous transaction to intIOout.

Comment: You need to edit these changes into your question.

Comment: Did you want to update your testbench to match and rerun your simulation? In any case, I still can't quite figure out what the protocol for `en` and `rdy` is supposed to be and whether or not your testbench is actually adhering to that protocol. You really need to have a clear idea of what you want to happen -- clear enough that you can explain it to others (us) -- before you start writing an implementation.

Comment: I've updated and rerun it. I apologize for the unclear naming, perhaps I should change it. As of now "en" switches output CE signal which allows SRAM ic to go into sleep mode. "rdy" controls extIO output cycles -- this way it doesn't write or read the same data several times. Probably it's not the best implementation.